# Mongoose give array custom name in schema

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, schema, mern

So I getting some information in a form.

So I wanna get the information from the form p.x a name and use it to name an array in a schema I am creating.

Here is what i kinda wanna do:

```
app.post('/edit-rooms', (req, res, next) =>{
  const Accomodation = require('../models/accomodation')
    Accomodation.findOne({email: req.session.passport.user}).lean().exec((err, user) => {

        if (err) {
          console.log(err, null);
        }  

        if (user) {
          const mongoose = require('mongoose');
          const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
          const AccomSchema = new Schema ({req.body.roomsleft : Array})
          const Accomodation = mongoose.model('accomodation', AccomSchema);
          Accomodation.update({
            roomsleft: req.body.roomsleft,
            {req.body.roomsleft}: {
              roomnum: req.body.roomnumber,
              single: req.body.single,
              double: req.body.double,
              king: req.body.king,
              superking: req.body.superking,
              bunk: req.body.bunk,
              sofa: req.body.sofa,
              button: req.body.button,
            },
            upsert: true
          })
          .exec()
      }
    })

})
```

So as you see i am getting a name from the body and trying to using it as the name of the array.

But obviously that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I am supposed to do that correctly?